# Phrase like "margin of error" or "buffer" but specifically about spare team capacity?

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests

I am trying to think of a phrase that means something like "margin of error" or "buffer," but specifically applying to spare capacity of a working team within a company. "Bench" sort of works for sports people, but it's not ideal because a bench is for players who can substitute in for other players, and I want to evoke the idea of additional workers waiting in the wings who can step in to accommodate a surge in demand.

I'm wanting to say something like

> We are operating with razor-thin _______"

... fill in the blank? And "margins" doesn't work because that sounds like it's about profitability. Any ideas?

Comment: Is that a bandwidth?

Comment: I can't square the "additional workers waiting in the wings" with "razor thin margin". It seems quite the opposite, plenty of *slack*.

Comment: @WeatherVane: right, maybe I was unclear. I'm looking for the phrase for "spare capacity" so that I can say "we have very limited/no spare capacity." "Slack" might work.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: hmm yes but hoping for something that refers to _spare_ bandwidth.

Comment: Sorry, it isn't at all clear whether there is spare capacity, or none.

Comment: razor-thin spare capacity

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm just looking for the term that means "spare capacity" (but is perhaps more specifically used in the context of a working team). Maybe my "fill in the blank" was confusing because it's about a _lack_ of spare capacity, but regardless, the term that goes _in the blank_ would still be a synonym for spare capacity. Whether there is or isn't any, it's still the same term. Clear?

Comment: @Lambie yes thanks but that isn't a commonly used phrase... is there a word that fits in the blank, or an alternate phrase, that's commonly used and means the same thing?

Comment: In writing phrases do not have to be "commonly used" to be fine. Any English speaker would accept that.

Comment: Are you looking for a sporting term? Or a term specifically related to staffing levels? Or something more general? You could try searching in a thesaurus for some of the answers you've rejected, e.g. https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/leeway

Comment: *Razor-thin reserve(s)* can apply to backup staff or capacity for work above and beyond.

Comment: You've already found it yourself - surge capacity - https://www.phe.gov/Preparedness/planning/mscc/handbook/chapter1/Pages/whatismedicalsurge.aspx#:~:text=Medical%20surge%20capacity%20refers%20to,laboratory%20studies%20or%20epidemiological%20investigations.